# Pasting a cell array of strings into the clipboard

Tags: matlab

If I have a cell array of strings, what is the best way to copy it to the clipboard so that I could paste it into an Excel spreadsheet (each string goes into a separate cell)? I know I can paste one element like so: `clipboard('copy', x{1})`, but how can I quickly paste the whole content of `x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer**

The trick is to tab-delimit your data: tabs separating columns, newlines separating rows.

This code below could be rewritten for better efficiency (by eliminating the string concat for each row) but you get the idea. For huge datasets, you're better off using `dlmwrite()` to avoid memory limitations.

**Example**

```
function fancyClipboard(myCell)
  if ~iscell(myCell), error('Input must be a cell'); end
  if ndims(myCell) > 2, error('Only 1D & 2D cells supported.'); end

  str = [];
  newline = sprintf('\n');
  for i = 1:size(myCell, 1); 
    row = sprintf('%s\t', myCell{i,:});
    row(end) = newline;
    str = [str row]; %#ok<AGROW>
  end
  clipboard('copy',str);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way if you don't want to mess with automation:

1. Double click on the variable in the workspace.
2. In the `Variables` window click on the top-left box to select the entire cell array.
3. Right-click -> copy. Paste to wherever you like!

I have tested this with R2012b in Linux with Libre Office. It should work with Excel as well.

Comment: It works, the only drawback is that every string in Excel spreadsheet will be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @Leo Yes, this is true. I haven't found a work around for that yet.